# mysql fulltext first/last nickname search is slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, full-text-search

I am using a fulltext search against a 30-40 mill records data base. 80% of it is in one table . I am doing a search on first and last name as full text because the full names can be stored in multiple ways "bill gates" "gates, bill" "bill and Melinda gates" etc.. we also have a database for nicknames so it will search for 'bill', 'will', 'william' etc.. It takes no time at all to find the nicknames but once i implemented the query to include the nicknames it is now taking a significantly longer time.

```
SELECT * FROM db1 
WHERE MATCH (Name) AGAINST (' +bill +gates 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) UNION ALL 
... (then the other 8 dbs the same) limit 500
```

compared to:

```
SELECT * FROM db1 
WHERE MATCH (Name) AGAINST (' +("bill" "will" "william") +gates 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) UNION ALL 
... (then the other 8 dbs the same) limit 500
```

Is there a way to speed this up? The searches are taking 40+ seconds compared to 3-5 seconds. Names like bill gates easily should hit the 500 mark seem to be taking longer even though there are more chances for it to hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use search-engines instead of MySql it will save Your time.
Look at Solr or Sphinx.

Sphinx have mysql addon.